# Can't loop elements when using an external library : Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use react-responsive caroussel. When adding my images manually, it works with no problem, but when adding them through photos.map, it doesn't work anymore and I get this error:

Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Any idea here?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"

interface Props {
  photos?: string[];
}
const Caroussel = ({
    photos = ["test1.png", "test2.png"]
  }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Carousel>
                                            //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        {photos.map((image) => (
          <div>
            <img src={image} />
          </div>
        ))}

                                            //THIS WORKS
        <div>
            <img src="test.png" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="test2.png" />
        </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default Caroussel;
```

Comment: I ve tried this:
const Caroussel = dynamic(() => import('Caroussel'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading() {
    return <Caroussel />;
  },
});

Comment: works if you type Caroussel as React.FunctionComponent<Props>.  [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-chaplygin-1pbt7)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap it into Reqct.Fragment:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"

interface Props {
  photos?: string[];
}
const Caroussel = ({
  photos = ["test1.png", "test2.png"]
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Carousel>
// Wrap it into React Fragment
      <>{photos.map((image) => (
        <div>
          <img src={image} />
        </div>
      ))}</>


      <div>
        <img src="test.png" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="test2.png" />
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default Caroussel;
```

I believe thi is because [Carousel](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/components/Carousel.tsx#L24) expects `React.ReactChild[];` type but `Array.prototype.map` returns `JSX.Element[]`. These types are incompatible.

DOn't know why they did it. AFAIK, children should be typed as `React.ReactNode`. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

React.Fragment does not affect your HTML

Comment: It's actually not that easy... Doing this, i get the images in a single tag (even if it's a React Fragment and not a div). So the first slide contains 3 images, for exemple.

Comment: Try to wrap it into div instead of fragment

Comment: Still not, then I get 2 divs... I tried forcing it with no success:
var tags:React.ReactElement[] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
    tags.push(
      <div key={photos[i].id}>
        <img src={photos[i].file} />
      </div>
    );
  }

Comment: As if it was expecting one single tag indeed, even though i can add multiple divs with no problem.
Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.

Comment: Please provide your output html or in sandbox

Comment: Here is my last try (no map anymore): https://jsfiddle.net/cu51mvpL/1/#&togetherjs=b3Q0oN4Gny